# How to extract conditional operators from the given string in php?

Tags: php, regex, operators, preg-match

I have a function call extractValues() and have a array with conditional operators to pass on it. What I exactly need is , split the string and operator. For example:

```
$arr = array('username='=> 'Alex','id >'=>'4');
extractValues($arr);
```

I need to split operators and strings available inside $arr keys and store into two separate variables. Remember all array keys are dynamic. and there may be space between string and conditional operator or may not be.

Operators expected inside the array keys are :

```
$operators = array('=','!=', '<', '<=', '>', '>=', 'like', 'clike', 'slike', 'not', 'is', 'in', 'between', 'and', 'or');
```

Comment: And why did you design your array to have keys like this in the first place? Having a separate "operator" key with a value of ">" would have made your life easier

Comment: @MarkBaker I assume the array is the result of former processing. The OP told that he want's a structure like you supposed

Comment: Your tags look like you already considered regular expressions. Did you take a look at `preg_split`? With `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` you could split by the operator plus optional whitespace and still get the operator itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside other possibilities, you can use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to achieve this. I'm not sure if I understood your question right, but I've prepared and example that should help. It translates the original array to an array that has the following structure:

```
array(
  array('key', 'operator', 'value'),
  array('key', 'operator', 'value'),
  array('key', 'operator', 'value'),
  // ...
)
```

Here comes the code:

```
$arr = array('username='=> 'Alex','id >'=>'4');
$result = extractValues($arr);
var_dump($result);

function extractValues($arr) {
    $pattern  = '/([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z_0-9]?)[ ]?(!=|=|<=|<|>=|';
    $pattern .= '>|like|clike|slike|not|is|in|between|and|or)/';

    $result = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        preg_match($pattern, $key, $matches);
        $result []= array($matches[1], $matches[2], $value);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(8) "username"
    [1] =>
    string(1) "="
    [2] =>
    string(4) "Alex"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(2) "id"
    [1] =>
    string(1) ">"
    [2] =>
    string(1) "4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi hek2mgl, your example works but small error i receive when i am trying with other operators for example - $arr = array('username<='=> 'Alex','id >'=>'4'); If i use != or >= then above example not works.

Comment: @SanjayDey You'll have to change the order of operators in the regex pattern. Check my update. Now it works